# Groupby multiple columns and aggregation with dask

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, dask

**dask dataframe** looks like this:

```
A     B     C     D
1     foo   xx    this
1     foo   xx    belongs
1     foo   xx    together
4     bar   xx    blubb
```

i want to groupy by columns A,B,C and join the strings from D with a blank between, to get

```
A     B     C     D
1     foo   xx    this belongs together
4     bar   xx    blubb
```

i see how to do this with pandas:

`df_grouped = df.groupby(['A','B','C'])['D'].agg(' '.join).reset_index()`

how can this be achieved with dask?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ddf = ddf.groupby(['A','B','C'])['D'].apply(lambda row: ' '.join(row)).reset_index()
ddf.compute()
```

Output:

```
Out[75]: 
   A    B   C                      D
0  1  foo  xx  this belongs together
0  4  bar  xx                  blubb
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a CustomAggregation, where both the per-chunk and aggregation operations are your `' '.join` method.

https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#custom-aggregation